# Rails simple_form association typeahead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using simple-form in Rails.
I have an input for with an association:

```
        <%= f.association :vendor, :label_method => :vendor_name, :label => 'Vendor' %>
```

If you select the dropdown and start typing, it will search the dropdown values.  But, most of the time you can only do one letter.  If you type real fast you might get more.

Is there a way to let the user keep typing at a slower pace.

For instance:

You type `l`, you get `lawn`, you type `la` and get `apple`.  But, I want `la` = `lawn`

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is browser specific.  You could always add one of the many jquery plugins that enhance select boxes, a la [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: interesting question, I'd be interested too in this. have you found any solution?